# Let $~z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}}~$ and $~\theta =z+z^2+z^4~$. Then...

Tags: extension-field, roots-of-unity

> Let $~z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}}~$ and $~\theta =z+z^2+z^4~$. Then which of following are correct?
>
> $1. ~~~ \theta \in \mathbb{Q}$
>
> $2. ~~~\theta \in \mathbb{Q}(D)$ for some $D>0$
>
> $3. ~~~\theta \in \mathbb{Q}(D)$ for some $D<0$
>
> $4. ~~~\theta \in i~\mathbb{R}$

I don't know how to start, I didn't got any progress with moreras theorem.
I think required some extension field result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\theta^2=(z+z^2+z^4)^2 = z^2+z^4+z^8+2z^3+2z^5+2z^6 = z+z^2+2z^3+z^4+2z^5+2z^6$$
$$ \theta^2+\theta = 2(z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6) = 2\left[\frac{z^7-1}{z-1}-1\right] = -2 \tag{A}$$
where $(A)$ implies $\theta=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}{2}$. It is not difficult to prove that $\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}$ is positive, hence the imaginary part of $\theta$ is positive and $\theta=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Define $\digamma(z)=z^2$, let $\Phi_7$ be the 7th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), and for any endofunction $f$ write $f^{\circ n}$ for $n$-fold composition. Then

$$\begin{align}\digamma^{\circ 3}(z)&=z + z(z-1)\Phi_7(z)\\
\theta(\digamma(z))&=\theta(z)+z(z-1)\Phi_7(z)\text{.}
\end{align}$$

2. You can look up the Galois group, Hasse diagram of intermediate fields, and other number-theoretic facts about $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ at the [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/6.0.16807.1).

To solve this problem you need to know:

1. what [algebraic field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}/N}$ generates over $\mathbb{Q}$,
2. the [Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field#Properties) of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ as well as its action on the generator $\zeta_N$,
3. the [Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), and
4. the [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups) of the subgroups of cyclic groups.

You should find that $\theta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

One can also show directly that $\theta(z)$ satisfies the quadratic equation
$\theta(z)^2+\theta(z)+2=(z^2-z+2)\Phi_7(z)$. However, to *know in advance* that such a relation exists, you really need to use Galois theory.

Comment: I didn't got the connection to my problem, more specifically something please

Comment: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Any  other simpler explanation possible?

Comment: Added an elementary (though unmotivated) method at the end.

Comment: what about 4th option will it be true, thanks

Comment: What can you say about the roots of $r^2+r+2=0$?